# Hadoop installation: Namenode cannot be started

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Currently I am trying to install hadoop-2.6.0 on my ubuntu 14.10 (32 bit utopic). I followed the instruction from here:

http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/install-apache-hadoop-ubuntu-14-10-centos-7-single-node-cluster.html#axzz3X2DuWaxQ

However, namenode cannot be started when I try to format namenode.

This is what I keep receiving when I try to do hdfs or hadoop namenode -format:

```
15/04/11 16:32:13 FATAL namenode.NameNode: Fialed to start namenode
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
    at             org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNSStorage.getStorageDirectory(NNStorage.java:329)
    at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.initJournals(FSEditLog.java: 270)
    at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.initJournalsForWrite(FSEditLog.java:241)
    at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:935)
    at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1379)
    at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1504)
15/04/11 16:32:13 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
15/04/11 16:32:14 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ThinkPad-Edge-E540/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

I am new to linux and hadoop. Please help me out on this issue. Also, when I first tried to install hadoop, I was receiving error message like this:

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Call From ThinkPad-Edge-E540/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Later, I uninstalled hadoop 2.6.0 and now I'm trying to follow current instruction as shown in the above link.

Update

I have removed all previous installed java (jdk1.7.0) that I installed in previous version. But the error message is still there.

Update

This is what showing in my etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 myname-mycomputer (I have commented out this line per suggestion)

#The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1       ip6-localhost  ip6-loopback
fe00::0   ip6-localnet
ff00:0    ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1   ip6-allnodes
ff02::2   ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Delete the line with `127.0.1.1` in /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Not working. Now even have a new error: java.net.UnkownHostException

Comment: `java.net.UnkownHostException` error occurs since you dont have your ip-address pointing to a hostname in your `/etc/hosts` file. I have added a answer, try it.

Answer (score 5):

This problem arise when mistaken I specified wrong path for namenode and datanode in hdfs-site.xml and tmp dir path in core-site.xml,
Path should be well formatted, for example-

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.edits.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoop-content/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoop-content/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
```

and for temp dir in core-site.xml it is like -

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/hadoop-content/tmp</value>
</property>
```

sometimes we make mistake in specifying - `file:///`

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/hosts`:

**1. Add this line:**

```
your-ip-address    your-host-name
```

example: `192.168.1.8    master`

In `/etc/hosts`:

**2. Delete the line with `127.0.1.1` (This will cause loopback)**

**3. In your core-site**, change `localhost` to `your-ip` or `your-hostname`

Now, restart the cluster.

Comment: I tried getting my ip-address with ifconfig. It shows two results: 1). lo (local loopback): inet addr: 127.0.0.1 Mask:255.255.255.0. 2) wlan0 (Ethernet): inet addr: 10.0.0.10 Bcast: 10.0.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0. Which onie should I use? This seems to be dynamic address, will it work if I change the network connection? Thanks

Comment: In addition, there is no localhost in my hdfs-site.xml. (See the instruction here: http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/install-apache-hadoop-ubuntu-14-10-centos-7-single-node-cluster.html#comment-10292)

Comment: After I changed my ip-address in /etc/hosts per your suggestion (I use 10.0.0.10 in this case), the error message is not changed.

Comment: Try changing `localhost` in `core-site.xml` to your-ip. Could you post your hosts file?

Comment: I did that already in original question. I've quit on this instruction. I followed another instruction, and it works fine! http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php