# Hadoop single node installation : Fails to start namenode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have given all the configurations as per [this](http://tecadmin.net/setup-hadoop-2-4-single-node-cluster-on-linux/) document. Using the same installation steps, while I have installed on one machine successfully. The other machine is showing the following error while starting the namenode

```
> 15/12/14 02:19:46 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries     
> 15/12/14 02:19:46 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component    at
> java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423) 
>>at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.getStorageDirectory(NNStorage.java:329)  

>>  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.initJournals(FSEditLog.java:276) 

>>  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.initJournalsForWrite(FSEditLog.java:247)
 >  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:985)
 
>>  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1429)

>>  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1554)

> 15/12/14 02:19:46 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1 15/12/14
> 02:19:46 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
> /************************************************************
```

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366270/what-does-uri-has-an-authority-component-mean ?

Comment: Have you tried the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583699/hadoop-installation-namenode-cannot-be-started

Comment: So am i supposed to not use UNC  url's in those xml files, is the way to give path locally just '<value>/home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode<value>' . I  couldnt find how to give file uri without unc conventions.

Comment: I dont think the issue is with the way you have defined the path, that seems correct to me, but in your steps to install there is no steps to disable ipv6..can you try that out and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the suggestions. It turned out to be a blooper, I have put only two /'s instead of three as given in the document for the URI. It works now !